# What are standard advert sizes for email newsletters?

Tags: email, wireframe

I am busy wireframing up an email newsletter template for a client of mine but for the life of me cannot find what standard sizes email adverts come in.

The width of my email is 600px but I have noticed that most leaderboards are 728x90, how does this fit in with the recommended 600-650px width?

Please help!

Comment: Are you asking how to scale or crop an image? There's no magic solution to getting 728 pixels into the space of 600-650. If usual newsletters are less wide than usual banners, I think we can logically conclude that newsletter ads are usually not usual banners.

Answer (score 1):

No there are very little standards for newsletters.

If you want a banner looking ad on your newsletter (or just a banner) simply resize your image to the proper width -> 600px for example. And keep your ratio.

Newsletter are usually 600px wide (in order to appear correctly under most circumstances). If you can't put a standard width advert banner in your newsletter, it's simply because that standard wasn't decided for this context. But a resized banner will look great in your newsletter, as long as you keep the image ratio you'll be fine. (you can use any tool, from paint to photoshop to resize an image)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're implementing HTML-e-mail over plain text - an I would really consider using relative sizes email reading is done a lot in smartphones these days where your suggested sizes would be wider than some phones max screen width. Relative is the cure for not using too wide images.